# django javascript code is not running but seperatly it is running

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I am trying to implement the code in django. My code works fine normally. But, when I try to use in django. It seems javascript not working. Why it is not working in django ? How can I run a html page that uses the javascript ?

*The html page lives in my template folder and in this folder, I have also a folder like `scripts/`.

Answer (score 1):

> *The html page lives in my template folder and in this folder, I have also folder like scripts/spryMap-2.js

You should not have your static files (eg spryMap-2.js) in your templates folder. It should go in your static files folder. Then you load your script with something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}scripts/spryMap-2.js"></script>
```

**Update:** I'm not sure why my answer was down voted. I've expanded my answer to provide more detailed instructions for fixing your static files.

The problem is your static files are not being served correctly - hence the 404 when you try to access the js file directly. As I mentioned above, the templates folder is not the right place for static files. You should configure your `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` settings. For example

```
#Make this the path to the folder where you will keep your static files
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/your/project/static'
#The absolute or relative URL which will serve your static files
STATIC_URL = '/static/' #translates to http://localhost:8000/static/, for example
```

and to get the django development server to serve your static files you will need the following in your urls.py

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: Do I have to do that? I mean it should work without using static url, since the .js file is still accessible in the same folder. What is the reason that does not run in the template folder ?

Comment: Basically, I believe your spryMap-2.js file is not being served, because the server (eg `manage.py runserver`) doesn't know that your static file is located in your templates folder. The django development server needs `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` to be properly configured in settings and needs your spryMap-2.js in the right folder.

Comment: I do not have STATIC_ROOT = '', I mean it is empty, do you think this is the reason that my code is not working ?

Comment: It's possible. Assuming your test page is at http://localhost:8000/ what happens when you visit http://localhost:8000/scripts/spryMap-2.js?

Comment: Page not found (404), since there is no defined url for this page ...?

Comment: The server doesn't know where to find your static files. You need to read the [django static files docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) - specifically, [Deploying static files in a nutshell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#deploying-static-files-in-a-nutshell), [Referring to static files in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#referring-to-static-files-in-templates) and [Serving static files in development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this code and it seems to be working fine, perhaps try checking the script source path tag. I used

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}assets/js/spryMap-2.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/spryMap-2.js"></script>
```

and i got the attached output which is draggable:
[image: Attached Output for the above problem]

Incase you are using Django make sure you mention the correct path in the settings file for the static path and put your sprymap.js file to that location, i guess this will sort the problem.

Comment: Try putting the .js file into the static folder, then try modifying the settings.py file to identify the static root, which in my case was.                                                                import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'project/static')